# Changing a post status name

Tags: post-status, trash

How do I change the status name "Trash" to "Archive". I don't want to change the functionality of the status or make a new status. I have tried Edit Flow custom status but I get some conflicts with another plugin and it seems a bit of a bulky solution for the small change I want to make.

It must be possible to just change the status name "Trash" to "Archive"?

I have looked through the WP admin files but I cant find any leads, maybe I am missing something.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this nice little bit of code from http://wpsnipp.com/index.php/functions-php/use-gettext-ngetext-to-replace-array-of-words-in-wpadmin/

```
 add_filter(  'gettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
 add_filter(  'ngettext',  'wps_translate_words_array'  );
   function wps_translate_words_array( $translated ) {

    $words = array(
                    // 'word to translate' = > 'translation'
                    'Posts' => 'Article',
                    'Post' => 'Articles',
                    'Pages' => 'Stuffing',
                    'Media' => 'Upload Images',
                    'Links' => 'Blog Roll',
                );

    $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($words),  $words,  $translated );
    return $translated;
   }
```

Add this to functions.php and change accordingly, although in saying that I have a custom plugin where I add things like this as it deactivates if I make a mistake, rather than functions.php which seems to break the website.

Comment: It seems I wasn't the first to have this idea http://www.doitwithwp.com/create-functions-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way is to [Change it's translation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress). From 'Trash' to 'Archive'. But this can have side-effects.

As I searched in the core file (modifying core-files is ALWAYS a BAD idea!!) there where no filter called, wich you coul hook into to Bypass...

Comment: Could you please provide an example on how you would alter the string "via its translation"? Hint: Search for answers on the `gettext` filter and how to trigger it only once.

Comment: That sounds more like it. Fiddling with po files seems a bit of drag. I will take a look at gettext and post the workaround. Thank you both